# Automatically joining multiple line segments in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art

I have `pst-solides3d` generated an ellipse. For some reason, the ellipse does not appear to be a single path in `Illustrator`, but rather multiple disjoint line segments. See below. I have exaggerated the stroke to show the disjointedness.

[image]

However, these line segments are perfectly aligned. If I choose two vertices I am able to **join** them. But considering the huge number of line segments, manually joining all segments is definitely not a good idea.

I'm wondering: `is there a way to automatically join multiple line segments one by one?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the free script Created by Hiroyuki Sato called "[Join Reasonably](http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/20-free-and-useful-adobe-illustrator-scripts--vector-3849)"

[image]

Comment: sorry, doesn't work.

Comment: its works with me just fine. try to select the whole path with the black arrow and run the script.

Comment: Shxt, I know why...the line segments I have are  actually squeezed rectangle...thanks for your answer. It should work, now I know.